# Can I cancel a flight reservation after a minor change?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I booked a flight from where I live now to Beijing and back, but I've gotten a new job and will be moving (interestingly, to the city that the flight has a layover in). Normally, I realize that changing the flight (even just canceling the first segment) would incur a change fee. That being said, last time I looked at the reservation, I saw this at the top of the web page:

Please note that the Airline has cancelled one or more of your selected flights. Please modify your reservation, or contact your travel agent for further information. (9115)
A schedule change has occurred on this trip. Please contact our call center in case you want to change or cancel this reservation. (15069)

Looking at the reservation, it appears that one of the legs of the flight has been changed such that instead of being operated by a regional carrier (Horizon Air, in this case), it will be operated directly by Alaska Airlines. All details of the flight (plane, departure, arrival, etc) appear to have remained the same.

Can I use this as grounds to cancel the reservation without a charge?

Comment: Probably not, but you might as well call them and ask.

Comment: It's schedule changes that put you in the driver's seat. Equipment / operating changes, hardly so. But yes, you need to call them.

Comment: I want to make sure I’m getting this right: You booked from city A to Beijing with a layover in city B. Because you are now moving from A to B, you want to cancel the entire holiday to Beijing?

Comment: For the record, it probably all depends on the conditions of carriage. So you would need to check precisely what the airline writes when a refund can be given. Or you can call them and ask them as openly as possible about all of your options.